# pgfplots - How can I set all the default line widths / thickness values to a certain value?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Upon discussion and examining a few printouts (by my own printer) of some pages of a document, I decided to try and change the line widths to another default value, e.g. `semithick` (a little increase to `0.6pt` from the default `0.4pt`, which equal `thin`). The printouts by the big commercial machines in a shop might produce satisfactory results for `thin` but I'd like to do it the 'rather safe than sorry'-way.

How can one do this?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
tikz,
pgfplots,
}

\usetikzlibrary{
intersections,
calc
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw
    (0,0) coordinate (A)
    (3,3) coordinate (B)
    (0.5,1) coordinate (C)
    (2.5,1) coordinate (D)
    ;
    \draw[thick] (A) rectangle (B);
    \draw[orange, ultra thick, ->] (C) -- (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot {rand};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On page 126 in "12.2.1 Creating a Picture Using an Environment", the TikZ manual provides the following information:

> `/tikz/every picture`                           (style, initially empty)
>
> This style is installed at the beginning of each picture.
>
> `\tikzset{every picture/.style=semithick}`
>
> Note that you should not use `\tikzset` to set options directly. For instance, if you want to use a line width of 1pt by default, do not try to say `\tikzset{line width=1pt}` at the beginning of your document. This will not work since the line width is changed in many places. Instead, say `\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=1pt}}`. This will have the desired effect.

For creating the the intended effect on

- axis line width,
- plot line width,
- grid line width and
- legend line width,

I implemented the relevant code in the MWE. Implied and accepted is of course that `\draw` commands without any further detailed line widths will adhere to these settings.

**If anyone has experience with this or spotted an error please do leave a comment or a reply with improvements.**

### Picture of Solution

[image]

### Solution

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
tikz,
pgfplots,
}

\usetikzlibrary{
calc
}

%===================================================
%SOLUTION STARTS HERE - comment out to see change
%===================================================
\newcommand{\mybasiclinewidth}{semithick}
%source is page 126 in the manual
\tikzset{
every picture/.style={
\mybasiclinewidth} %or use: "`line width=1 pt,"<-- note:if you write line width, you must use a value with unit
}
\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style={
\mybasiclinewidth,
grid style={
    \mybasiclinewidth,
},
tick style={
    \mybasiclinewidth,
},
},
}
%===================================================
%SOLUTION ENDS HERE - comment out to see change
%===================================================

\newcommand{\linevertspace}{-0.3cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
\draw
(0,0) coordinate (thinLEFT)
($(thinLEFT)+(0,\linevertspace)$) coordinate (semithicktestLEFT)
($(semithicktestLEFT)+(0,\linevertspace)$) coordinate (semithickLEFT)
($(semithickLEFT)+(0,\linevertspace)$) coordinate (thickLEFT)
%
($(thinLEFT)+(3,0)$) coordinate (thinRIGHT)
($(semithicktestLEFT)+(3,0)$) coordinate (semithicktestRIGHT)
($(semithickLEFT)+(3,0)$) coordinate (semithickRIGHT)
($(thickLEFT)+(3,0)$) coordinate (thickRIGHT)
;
\draw[thin] (thinLEFT) -- (thinRIGHT) node [right] {thin};
\draw (semithicktestLEFT) -- (semithicktestRIGHT) node [right] {$\leftarrow$ default line width!};
\draw[semithick] (semithickLEFT) -- (semithickRIGHT) node [right] {semithick};
\draw[thick] (thickLEFT) -- (thickRIGHT) node [right] {thick};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot {rand};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```