# pgfplots ignores "thick" option for axes

Tags: pgfplots

I'm having a problem with the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
 \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[thick, smooth, no markers,
    xmin = -1.1, xmax = 1.1,
    ymin = -1.1, ymax = 1.1,
    axis lines = center,
    axis line style={->}, 
    xlabel = $\rho_{S}$,
    ylabel = $\rho_{\tau}$,
    xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south}
    ]
    \addplot[name path = OBEN, samples = 1000, black, domain = -1:1]
    {min(1, 0.5+1.5*x)};
    \addplot[name path = UNTEN, samples = 1200, black, domain= -1:1]
    {max(-1, -0.5+1.5*x)};
    \addplot[pattern = north west lines] fill between[of=OBEN and UNTEN];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The axes aren't drawn thick as indicated by the option `thick`. I get:

[image]

instead of something like

[image]

Excuse the different zooms levels but it should be clear that I'm not getting `thick`axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **axis line style = thick** option

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
 \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis line style = thick, smooth, no markers,
    xmin = -1.1, xmax = 1.1,
    ymin = -1.1, ymax = 1.1,
    axis lines = center,
    axis line style={->}, 
    xlabel = $\rho_{S}$,
    ylabel = $\rho_{\tau}$,
    xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south}
    ]
    \addplot[name path = OBEN, samples = 1000, black, domain = -1:1]
    {min(1, 0.5+1.5*x)};
    \addplot[name path = UNTEN, samples = 1200, black, domain= -1:1]
    {max(-1, -0.5+1.5*x)};
    \addplot[pattern = north west lines] fill between[of=OBEN and UNTEN];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Ref: [pgfplots - How can I set all the default line widths / thickness values to a certain value?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206734/pgfplots-how-can-i-set-all-the-default-line-widths-thickness-values-to-a-cer)