# Change all line width proportionally

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, line

How do I change all line width proportionally to one another for example by a factor of two?

Here is an MWE to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 1cm]{standalone}

%some magic line which changes all the line width by a factor of two

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[thin]  (0,0) -- ++(2,0);

    \draw        (0,1) -- ++(2,0);

    \draw[thick] (0,2) -- ++(2,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is not related to [pgfplots - How can I set all the default line widths / thickness values to a certain value?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206734/pgfplots-how-can-i-set-all-the-default-line-widths-thickness-values-to-a-cer) because I dont just want to change one line widths.

The default line width should not be change.

Comment: The MWE is *very* useful because we now know that you want to use `thin`, `thick` and alike, but wish for a one-line way of changing all of these definitions. So yes, the MWE *is* needed.

Answer (score 15):

The line widths `thin`, `thick`, etc. are defined liked this (taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106743/103046)):

```
\tikzset{
    ultra thin/.style= {line width=0.1pt},
    very thin/.style=  {line width=0.2pt},
    thin/.style=       {line width=0.4pt},
    semithick/.style=  {line width=0.6pt},
    thick/.style=      {line width=0.8pt},
    very thick/.style= {line width=1.2pt},
    ultra thick/.style={line width=1.6pt}
}
```

So I would suggest to replace this definition with every line widths given as a multiple of some length variable (say `\mylinewidth`). You can then change the value of `\mylinewidth` globally or locally, and the lines with these options will adjust their widths.

Example (note the comment below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\mylinewidth
\setlength\mylinewidth{0.4pt}

\tikzset{
    ultra thin/.style= {line width=0.25\mylinewidth},
    very thin/.style=  {line width=0.5\mylinewidth},
    thin/.style=       {line width=\mylinewidth},
    semithick/.style=  {line width=1.5\mylinewidth},
    thick/.style=      {line width=2\mylinewidth},
    very thick/.style= {line width=3\mylinewidth},
    ultra thick/.style={line width=4\mylinewidth},
    every picture/.style={semithick}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thin]  (0,0) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw        (0,1) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw[very thick] (0,2) -- ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\setlength\mylinewidth{1pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thin]  (0,0) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw        (0,1) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw[very thick] (0,2) -- ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: In this example, I used `semithick` as the default line width because it appeared visually right to me. You can of course use the standard default which is `every picture/.style={thin}`.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Good answer. Sad this isnt a function in pgf. Why do you use every picture/.style={semithick}?

Comment: @Julian_W: Try to leave that out, and `\draw` without an option will not join in the scaling. So with this line I make `semithick` the default for all pictures, and all lines (even without an own specified width) will be affected by a change of `\mylinewidth`.

Comment: why dont you use the standard \thin?

Comment: @Julian_W I had the visual impression that `semithick` was the standard. In case I assumed wrongly, feel free to make a different choice in your code.

Comment: made the change, when its peer reviewed Im gonna accept the answer. \thin is definitively the default line width. It even says it in the link you provied :)

Comment: everyone else looking at this question will not notice the last sentence and have lines which are twice as thick. Please change that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64880/discussion-between-julian-w-and-tiuri).